# Difference between Array and Table

Tags: c

In the recent interview, I was asked, what is your favorite subject. I said C programming. The next question was, What is the difference between `Table` and `Array`?
Can anyone help me with it. I have never heard about tables in C.

Comment: C doesn't have a language nor library feature named "tables". I suspect your interviewer was either terribly ignorant of the language (or used very incorrect terminology for a 2D array) or it was a trick question. How did you respond and how did your interviewer respond to your answer?

Comment: table could refer to map or dictionary, that depend of your interpretation of what is a table.

Comment: You should have said that in the interview.  If you tried to wing it and made something up then you probably won't hear back.

Comment: The first thing "table" makes me think of is SQL or a relational database.  There are lots of ways of implementing a table-like data structure in C.  *Very* poor interview question, I'd say.  (Unfortunately, of course, there's no line judge who can give you credit if you fail to properly answer what turns out to have been a poor or unanswerable question.)

Comment: An array is where the data is kept in your program. A table is how you present that data to the user.

Answer (score 3):

Array is a built-in feature of the C language. Table is used by Programmer to write C program, along with Chair and Computer.

Arrays decay into pointers to their first element in most expression contexts.

Tables decay into dust and rust, which may or may not replace C in the long run.

Comment: Some programmers prefer tableless developing - using sofas and laptops.

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of table in C programming. Probably you could have asked the interviewer, did he mean by multi-level array OR array of arrays.

Comment: I said to him that the difference is Array is a part of C programming while Table is not. He started laughing though.

Answer (score 0):

From a typical idioms point of view, I would say: think about the common expressions “indexed array” and “lookup table”. When I say “indexed”, “adressable” is to be read too. A computer’s memory is an array, while in a database, you have tables. One may say an array is a special case of table.